# Join a table with condition based on values with "flags"

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got a problem with a MySQL query.

Suppose we have two tables:

cars:

| id | brand | owner_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | toyota | 24 |
| 2 | ford | 56 |
| ... | ... | ... |

car_debts:

| id | value | car_id(fk) | fl_unique(boolean) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 24 | 50.0 | 1 | 0 |
| 25 | 40.0 | 1 | 0 |
| 26 | 90.0 | 1 | 1 |
| 27 | 10.0 | 2 | 0 |
| 28 | 20.0 | 2 | 0 |
| 29 | 30.0 | 2 | 0 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

I want to produce a result like this:

| car_debts.id | car_debts.values | cars.id | car_debts.fl_unique(boolean) | cars.brand |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 24 | 0.0 | 1 | 0 | toyota |
| 25 | 0.0 | 1 | 0 | toyota |
| 26 | 90.0 | 1 | 1 | toyota |
| 27 | 10.0 | 2 | 0 | ford |
| 28 | 20.0 | 2 | 0 | ford |
| 29 | 30.0 | 2 | 0 | ford |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

So, basically querying the result takes into account the "fl_unique" flag.
If car_debts has "fl_unique" as true in some row, only the value with the flag should be considered, the other values ​​need to be 0.0. If they don't have the flag as true, nothing changes in the values.

This is a simple abstraction of my problem. Thanks for any help or tips!

Comment: What exactly did you try, what do you want to know? How to JOIN, how to apply a conditional SUM? What is your question?

Comment: I want to know how to join those tables based on the "flag" condition specified. Some values need to me modified if the the flag is set true. @JonasMetzler

Comment: "*If car_debts has 'fl_unique' as true in some row, only the value with the flag should be considered, the other values ​​need to be 0.0*" - Your expected output doesn't match your description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following steps can be found on [this example](https://dbfiddle.uk/kiqbXw1H).

First start by finding which distinct car_id have fl_unique true (0), this can be achieved by using :

```
select car_id
from car_debts
group by car_id
having SUM(fl_unique <> 0)>0
```

The we can use join and case expression as follows:

```
select cd.id,
       case when tbl.car_id is null then cd.value 
            when cd.fl_unique = 1 and tbl.car_id is not null then cd.value
            when fl_unique=0  and tbl.car_id is not null then  0.0 end as value,
       c.id,
       cd.fl_unique,
       c.brand,
       tbl.car_id
from car_debts cd
left join (select car_id
           from car_debts
           group by car_id
           having SUM(fl_unique <> 0)>0 
           ) tbl on tbl.car_id=cd.car_id
inner join cars c on c.id=cd.car_id;
```

*Note* The left join with the subquery helps to create the case conditions .

If all group values of car_id (in your example 2) are null then we select  value as are

Answer (score 1):

Use `MAX()` window function to get the max value of `fl_unique` for each `car_id` and compare it to the current value of `fl_unique`.
If they are not the same this means that the returned `value` must be `0`, else `value`:

```
SELECT d.id,
       (MAX(d.fl_unique) OVER (PARTITION BY d.car_id) = d.fl_unique) * d.value AS value,
       d.car_id, 
       d.fl_unique,
       c.brand
FROM car_debts d INNER JOIN cars c
ON c.id = d.car_id;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/mwIgdMBh).